# How to reduce differential operator to a 4th order ODE of the standard Euler type?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, physics, recreational-mathematics, mathematical-physics, fluid-dynamics

[image: Image here]

I read this article [https://mae.ufl.edu/~uhk/STOKES-DRAG-FORMULA.pdf](https://mae.ufl.edu/%7Euhk/STOKES-DRAG-FORMULA.pdf)
How do we actually arrive to a 4th order ODE below?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just plug in? Observe
$$
D\sin^2 \theta \equiv  \sin\theta ~\partial_\theta\! \left (\frac {1}{\sin\theta}\partial_\theta \right )~  \sin^2 \theta= -2 \sin^2 \theta,
$$
so that you may substitute the eigenvalue for *D*,
$$
Q^2 f \sin^2\theta = \left (\partial_r^2 +{D\over r^2}\right)^2 f \sin^2\theta= \sin^2\theta ~~ (\partial_r^2-2/r^2)^2f\\   =
\sin^2\theta ~~\left (f''''-{4\over r^2} f''+{8\over r^3} f' -{8\over r^4}f\right).
$$